# How to integrate Jira with python flask app using oAuth 2.0?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, jira, jira-rest-api

I can access Jira from my flask app using Basic auth which requires username and api token but due to security issues, I want to use oAuth for the same. I followed the oAuth 2.0 docs (https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/oauth-2-3lo-apps/) but on creating the app in Jira, it is created as private and no other user can access it. If anyone else wants access, they have to create an app in their own Jira account and pass those credentials to the backend.

1. How do other services like github and servicenow etc. implement this? Basic auth or oAuth?
2. Is it secure from user point of view to make their own app in Jira and then copy and pass the credentials to the backend api?
3. The access token which is generated after passing the credentials in Jira api has an expiry time of 1 hour and I can't find anything on refresh tokens. Does this mean that a user has to give access to his Jira account every time he logs in to my platform?

Comment: Please ask only one question per question and make sure it [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)!

Comment: I want to implement the functionality on my platform so I have to ask whether I am taking the right approach or I should just stick to basic auth. While implementing, I also have to ensure security, hence the second question.